# Import data from multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, import

I have retrieved data from database. Structure looks like this.

```
$array = array ( array ('name'=>'oscar', 'surname'=>'trump', 'age'=>'40'),array ('name'=>'ben', 'surname'=>'simmons', 'age'=>'22'), array ('name'=>'daniel', 'surname'=>'green', 'age'=>'12'));
```

I would like to import this data into my database. Which has the same structure. ID, name , surname , age. I understand there must be some kind of loop, but I cant really manage to get there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `foreach` loop you can...

```
<?php
    $array = array ( array ('name'=>'oscar', 'surname'=>'trump', 'age'=>'40'),array ('name'=>'ben', 'surname'=>'simmons', 'age'=>'22'), array ('name'=>'daniel', 'surname'=>'green', 'age'=>'12'));
    foreach($array as $field=>$values){
        echo "insert into `table_name` set `name`='".$values['name']."', `surname`='".$values['surname']."', `age`='".$values['age']."';";
        echo "<br />";
    }
?>
```

Output,

```
insert into `table_name` set `name`='oscar', `surname`='trump', `age`='40';
insert into `table_name` set `name`='ben', `surname`='simmons', `age`='22';
insert into `table_name` set `name`='daniel', `surname`='green', `age`='12';
```